# Autofix Babel 6.4: A semicolon is required after a class property

Tags: webpack, babeljs, jslint

I am trying to upgrade to Babel to 6.4. After fixing a bunch of problems with `require`, Now I have ton of error about missing semicolons:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/views/HomePage/main.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/chris/ss/components/views/HomePage/main.js: A semicolon is required after a class property (16:23)
  14 | @connectToStores
  15 | class HomePage extends Component{
> 16 |   static propTypes = {}
     |                        ^
  17 |
  18 |   static contextTypes = {
  19 |     onSetBodyClass: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/chris/ss/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1425:13)
    at Parser.pp.parseClassProperty (/Users/chris/ss/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2577:10)
    at Parser.parseClassProperty (/Users/chris/ss/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:3785:20)
    at Parser.pp.parseClassBody (/Users/chris/ss/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2482:34)
    at Parser.pp.parseClass (/Users/chris/ss/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2425:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/Users/chris/ss/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1889:19)
    at Parser.parseStatement (/Users/chris/ss/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:3574:22)
    at Parser.pp.parseBlockBody (/Users/chris/ss/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2294:21)
    at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (/Users/chris/ss/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1823:8)
```

Is there a linter or some utility that can fix all of these automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Wow people are really getting worked up over this! [See this issue on the Babel Repo](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/3225#issuecomment-171619722)

It appears after reading this that Babel is going to change this.

Also, [this response to the same issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/3225#issuecomment-171303451) recommends reverting Babel versions until the issue is resolved like so:

**package.json**

```
"babel": "<6.3.0",
"babel-cli": "<6.3.0",
"babel-core": "<6.3.0",
"babylon": "<6.3.0",
```

From what I can tell the poroposed TC39 specification for this is still up in the air though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSCS' requireSemicolons rule to autofix this.

https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs/pull/2057 - Added this in version 2.9.0.